# Is there any difference betwwen these two forms of for-loop?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, iteration, overlap

I have set of patterns

> ATGCG GCATG CATGC AGGCA GGCAT

which I need to find the overlap between them. I'm using this function and it works correctly:

```
def get_overlap(patterns):
    n = len(patterns[0])-1
    return [(left,right) for left,right in product(patterns,patterns) if left != right and left.endswith(right[:n])]
```

My question is: why it doesn't loop through all the patterns when I am using the ordinary for loop form?

```
for left, right in product(patterns, patterns):
    if left != right and left.endswith(right[:n]):
        return [left, right]
```

it prints the last item only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution basically says "return all (left, right) pairs that match the following criteria"

The second solution says "search for a pair, that matches the following criteria. As soon as one is found, return it". Therefore only one is returned. I haven't tested this, but I it should be the first one encountered, not the last one.

To fix it: instead of returning a pair which is found in the second solution, add it to an array of solutions, and return that array after the for loop.